# Reduce a jquery function to show hide div

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I've created a form that shows or hides Country.

This is a part of the code, very raw code.

I need to reduce this function for the page load and to make it easier.

```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".selezioneprovincia input").bind("change", function() {
        if ($('.selezioneprovincia .AQ input').is(':checked')) {
            $(".selezionepv .AQ").show(); // checked
        } else {
            $(".selezionepv .AQ").hide(); // unchecked
            $(".selezionepv .AQ input").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if ($('.selezioneprovincia .CH input').is(':checked')) {
            $(".selezionepv .CH").show(); // checked
        } else {
            $(".selezionepv .CH").hide(); // unchecked
            $(".selezionepv .CH input").prop("checked", false);
        }
```

The function works, but i need to reduce, if possible, the part of show hide with the .AQ, .CH class, that classes are variable, they reference to the Country.
I imagine a way to get that class (the item has many classes) and put it in the function one time for every item.

Sorry for my english, i hope in any help.

Goodbye
M.

Comment: if the code works as intended then this is better to go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Add the HTML part too

Answer (score 0):

I think that,you Expecting Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selezioneprovincia input").change(function() {
        if ($(this.classname == AQ).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).show(); // checked
        } else {
            $(this).siblings().hide(); // unchecked
            $(this).siblings().prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some variables and also a function to simplify your code. Something like this:

```
function processCheck($checkInput, $container) {
  if($checkInput.is(':checked')) {
    $container.show()
  } else {
    $container.hide();
    $container.find('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
}

$(function() { 
  $('.selezioneprovincia input').change(function() {
    processCheck($('.selezioneprovincia .AQ input'), $('.selezionepv .AQ'));
    processCheck($('.selezioneprovincia .CH input'), $('.selezionepv .CH'));
  });
});
```